# (MacOS Terminal). How to produce a readable Epoch time from terminal

Tags: macos, awk, terminal, grep, dscl

I am trying to give a command to a friend who has been having account passwords changed. He is trying to determine a way to figure out when the password was last changed. I was able to give him this command, that is working in MacOS terminal, but I want to make it a bit nicer by providing a readable answer. Here is the command:

```
dscl . read /Users/username accountPolicyData | grep -A1 SetTime
```

which results in something like this:

```
    <key>passwordLastSetTime</key> 
    <real>1670348364.4110398</real>
```

This command is pulling the reset date and time great, but him having to search out an epoch time calculator may be a bit over his head. My question:

Do any of you have any idea how I could strip out the bracketed text and convert the epoch time from the commandline? I'm happy to drop the title line if that helps if doing so would allow a numerical conversion that is readable.

Thanks for any suggestion you may have.

Comment: Can you install GNU awk for time functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `defaults` to read plist :

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(mktemp /tmp/XXXXXXXX.plist)
dscl . read /Users/username accountPolicyData | tail -n +2 > $file 
c=$(defaults read $file passwordLastSetTime)
date -r ${c%.*} '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
rm $file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to extract the epoch time and convert it to a human-readable date and time:

```
dscl . read /Users/username accountPolicyData | grep -A1 passwordLastSetTime | awk '/real/ {print strftime("%c",$2)}'
```

Explanation:

- `dscl . read /Users/username accountPolicyData` is the same as before, it retrieves the account policy data for the specified username.
- `grep -A1 passwordLastSetTime` filters the output to show only the line containing passwordLastSetTime and the next line.
- `awk '/real/ {print strftime("%c",$2)}'` is an awk script that processes the filtered output. The script matches the line that contains real, extracts the second field (`$2`), and converts it from an epoch time to a human-readable date and time using the strftime function. The `%c` format string for strftime specifies a locale-specific date and time format.

Comment: That awk command requires GNU awk, it won't work with the BSD awk that comes with MacOS. You never need grep when you're using awk - that `grep | awk` pipeline is equivalent to `awk 'f{if (/real/) print ...; f=0} /passwordLastSetTime/{f=1}` but could probably be reduced to just `awk 'f{print ...; f=0} /passwordLastSetTime/{f=1}`

Comment: You'd also need to add `-F '>'` to separate the time into `$2`.